Spring Boot request to favicon.ico causes Access Denied Exception
I have a spring boot app which is not a web app, it's just a REST API app that provides data. When I request to a localhost URL from terminal or Postman, it works fine. But when I request to the same URL from browser, it gives result but in TRACE logging mode, it also prints Access Denied exception. Because it also sends a request to /favicon.ico under the hood. I want to get rid of this exception but I couldn't find a proper solution.
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled is deprecated in Spring Boot 2.7 version. So, not usable anymore.
2024-07-30T11:37:12.142+03:00 DEBUG 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /favicon.ico
2024-07-30T11:37:12.142+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (7/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Did not process request since did not find bearer token
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (8/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Did not process authentication request since failed to find username and password in Basic Authorization header
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (9/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.143+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (10/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.144+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.144+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (12/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.144+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-07-30T11:37:12.144+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-07-30T11:37:12.144+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.144+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (14/14)
2024-07-30T11:37:12.144+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing GET /favicon.ico
2024-07-30T11:37:12.144+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Denying request since did not find matching RequestMatcher
2024-07-30T11:37:12.148+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2024-07-30T11:37:12.148+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'refreshEventListener'
2024-07-30T11:37:12.148+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'startupTimeMetrics'
2024-07-30T11:37:12.148+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'
2024-07-30T11:37:12.148+03:00 TRACE 1963555 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    ....

Also, when I .permitAll() for /favicon.ico endpoint, it forwards to /error endpoint because /favicon.ico is not found. I can create a dummy /favicon.ico endpoint to not return anything in case of a request, but this doesn't seem best practise. There should be a better way to get rid of this issue.
I am using Spring Boot 3.3.2 version.

Static files have to be explicitly allowed - see my answer here

Why are you running with TRACE logging anyway. THis is TRACE it will not show up nor is an issue in production where you shouldn't be running with TRACE logging in the first place.

@JAsgarov there is no static file. It's not a web app.

@M.Deinum it causes unstability while using rate limiter.

Then don't request the favicon. You don't have one so it will either result in a 404 when you open it up (I still fail to see why that is a problem) or you leave the protection on and you get a 401. Feels like yu are solving a problem that isn't a problem. Also if this is a REST api why are you then accessing it using a browser? The browser will, by default, request the favicon. So if this is a REST api as you state, this is really a non issue as no-one will use a browser to access it.

@M.Deinum Yes it's a REST api and is not reached from browser in real use case. But I face with this error during local tests. I just want to know if there is a way to get rid of this or not

As stated it is not an error it is an informational TRACE error.

Put this small piece of code into a header section of your web site. Browser will be happy and will not ask for a favicon again.

<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">


This is not a web app.

"when I request to the same URL from browser" so don't use a web browser
